# Error connecting installing mysqlclient to my django project

Tags: python, mysql, django

please help, when i try to run pipenv install mysqlclient it gives me an error indicating that visual c++ 14 or greater is needed and now i have gotten 14.29 but still not working.I also tried usimg Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages and this showed that mysqlclient installed successfully but when i tried to run mysqlclient it gave an error saying do you have mysqlclient installed? please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use mysql-connector-python

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

in you settings.py you must add this line:

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
```

or you can use alternative

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

settings.py:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'
```

Comment: thank you soo much but it showed this 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You must install mysql-client for use it. sudo apt install mysql-server if you have apt based linux

Comment: its not installing

Comment: Can you try sudo apt-get install mariadb-client?